# Does a cover have to be a subset of the topology?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Say I have a topological space $M = (X, T)$ where $T = \{t_i \subset X\}$ is a collection of subsets of $X$.

Then if I define a cover $C = \{c_i \subset X\}$ such that $\bigcup_{i} c_i = X$, must the cover be a subset of the topology? That is, is it true that $C \subset T$? Or can the cover be completely unrelated to the topology?

Comment: It’s usually open covers that are of interest, i.e., ones that are subsets of the topology, but one can talk about other kinds; I would call your $C$ a cover of $X$ irrespective of whether it’s an open cover.

Comment: Ordinarily one refers to an "open cover," in which case $C\subset T$.

Comment: Is that because the topology defines what constitutes an open set?

Comment: The topology itself is the set of open sets w.r.t. that topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general definition in use requires a covering to be just a set (or sequence) $\mathfrak U$ of (non-empty?) subsets of $X$ such that $\bigcup\mathfrak U=X$. The term is used mostly in topology, so it is natural that the cases of interest will be related to the topology. Open covers are more interesting for several reasons. Another interesting class of coverings I can think of is the class of *fundamental* coverings:

> A fundamental covering of a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is a covering $\mathfrak U$ which satisfies the following equivalent conditions:
>
> 1. $V\subseteq X$ is open if and only if, for all $U\in\mathfrak U$, $V$ is open in the subspace topology of $U$. In other words, if and only if for all $U\in\mathfrak U$ there is an open set $W\in\tau$ such that $V\cap U=U\cap W$.
> 2. for any topological space $Y$, a function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if $\left.f\right\rvert_U$ is continuous (w.r.t. the subspace topology) for all $U\in\mathfrak U$.

A noticeable class of non-open coverings which satisfies (2) is the class of *locally finite closed coverings*, i.e. the closed coverings $\mathfrak U$ such that, for all $x\in X$, there exists a neighbourhood $V\ni x$ such that $C\cap V\ne\emptyset$ for a finite number of sets $C\in\mathfrak U$.

In a way, it generalises the property of the real line that says that, for instance, $$f=\begin{cases}3x+a&\text{if }x\le0\\-9x^2+b&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}$$

is continuous if and only if $a=b$.